# how to make spring web flux wait until specified condition met in server and then return the response

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm a starter in Spring Web-Flux. i want to have a reactive service for example named isConfirmed and this service must wait until another service of my server is called for example named confirm. both services are located in my server and the first reactive service must wait until the second service (confirm) is called and then return the confirm message. i want no threads to be blocked in my server until the second service is called. like an observer pattern. is it possible with spring web flux?

update: can we have this feature while server using distributed cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a CompletableFuture between your 2 services, something like that:

```java
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    
    public Mono<String> isConfirmed() {
        return Mono.fromFuture(future);
    }
    
    public void confirm(String confirmation) {
        future.complete(confirmation);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it won't block any thread on server?

Comment: No because the answer of isConfirmed won't be sent immediately and the thread it was using can do something else, then the thread that will be used in the service confirm will be the one triggering the first response

Comment: I have another question about this solution. what if i have multiple servers and distributed cache? still this solution can work?

Comment: Having this work in a multiple servers environment is indeed more complex. You will need an intermediate system, such as an event bus (such as RabbitMQ or Kafka), to spread the confirmation to all servers so it can be sent to all waiting clients.